# Excel: combining IF formula with FREQUENCIES and MATCH

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I'm trying to compbine an if-then and a frequency formula in Excel:

I need to get the sum of the values in column C1:C5 in cell C6, but only there is a match with the value in B1:B5 and A6.

So in the picture below, the result should be 25 (Tthe formula is in Dutch, but I'm using IF, SUM, FREQUENCY, MATCH)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one which you were trying shall render you only `SUM` of `UNIQUE` values i.e. for 1,2 or 3. However there is a workaround instead of using `MATCH Function` simply use the `FREQUENCY Function` with `IF` & `ROW Function` & wrap it within `SUMPRODUCT`!

**Perhaps** there is much easier way to of summing instead of using `FREQUENCY Function`, `FREQUENCY Function` also **slows down** the working functionality.

**Using FREQUENCY Function --> Formula used in cell C8**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FREQUENCY(IF($B$1:$B$5=$A6,ROW($C$1:$C$5)),ROW($C$1:$C$5)),$C$1:$C$6)
```

The easy way is using `SUMPRODUCT` `Function` this is because it **multiplies ranges or arrays together and returns the sum of products**. `SUMPRODUCT` is an **incredibly versatile function** which can be further used to `count` and `sum` like `COUNTIFS` or `SUMIFS`, but with more **flexibility**. **Other functions** can also easily be used inside `SUMPRODUCT` to **extend functionality even further**.

**Formula used in cell C7**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$B$5=$A$6)*($C$1:$C$5))
```

**Side Note:** The `SUMPRODUCT function` can be used to create array formulas that don't require **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**. This is the most important reason why `SUMPRODUCT` is been so **extensively** used to create more **advanced formulas**.

One main issues with array formulas is that they usually return incorrect results if they are not entered with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**. That said if someone forgets to confirm press `CSE` when entering a formula, the expected output may suddenly alter, nonetheless the actual formula did not change. Using `SUMPRODUCT` means the formulas will work in any version of Excel without special handling.

In **O365**, the formula engine handles arrays natively & can often use the `SUM` function in place of `SUMPRODUCT` in an array formula with the same desired output and you don't have to `press CSE`. If the same formula is opened in an earlier version of Excel, it will require `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`.

***Fundamentally SUMPRODUCT is a much safer option if a worksheet is used any version of Excel before MS365, even if the worksheet was created in MS365.***

[image: SUM_WITH_FREQUENCY]

Comment: Formula in `DUTCH` ---> • With `FREQUENCY` --> `=SOMPRODUCT(INTERVAL(ALS($B$1:$B$5=$A7;RIJ($C$1:$C$5));RIJ($C$1:$C$5));$C$1:$C$6)` • With `SUMPRODUCT` only  --> `=SOMPRODUCT(($B$1:$B$5=$A$7)*($C$1:$C$5))`

Answer (score 1):

Enter `=SUMIF($B$1:$B$5,A6,$C$1:$C$5)` or the Dutch equivalent into C6 and fill down.

Comment: Awesome, that did it, with just a few adjustments. For anyone reading: `=SOM.ALS($B$1:$B$5;$A$6;C1:C5)` (Dutch) `=SUMIF($B$1:$B$5,$A$6,C1:C5)` (English)