# Can SUMIFS calculate data from current month with 2 or more criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that uses a few SUMIFS formulas to calculate data based on 2 criteria and a normal range. Currently I'm having to change this manually every month to capture metrics of tickets reported that meet some of those criteria. Ideally i'd like to implement some logic to only calculate data that has dates from the current month.

Here's my original sumifs:

```
=SUMIFS($G$2:$G$100,$A$2:$A$100,"primary",B2:B100,"little")
=SUMIFS($G$2:$G$100,$A$2:$A$100,"primary",B2:B100,"panic")
```

etc..

I was told something to the extent of this would get me where I needed to be, but it doesn't seem to be actually calculating only data with dates within this month.

```
=SUMIFS($G$2:$G$100,$A$2:$A$100,"primary*",$B$2:$B$101,"little")+SUMIFS($G$2:$G$100,$F$2:$F$100,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Spreadsheet_data

[image]

Comment: Why not try using the incredibly versatile `SUMPRODUCT Function` instead of `SUMIFS`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try using the **Incredibly Versatile** **SUMPRODUCT Function** here,

Formula used in cell **I2**

```
    =SUMPRODUCT(($G$2:$G$9)*($A$2:$A$9=$J2)*($B$2:$B$9=$K2)*
     (TEXT($F$2:$F$9,"mmmmyyyy")=$I$1&YEAR(TODAY())))
```

[image: USING_SUMPRODUCT]

The **SUMPRODUCT** function simply multiplies arrays together and returns the **sum of products**. **If only one array is supplied, SUMPRODUCT will simply sum the items in the array**. Up to 30 ranges or arrays can be supplied.

It may seem *boring, complex, and even pointless.* **But** SUMPRODUCT is an **amazingly versatile function with many uses**. **Because it will handle arrays gracefully, you can use it to process ranges of cells in clever, elegant ways. It can be used to count and sum like COUNTIFS or SUMIFS, but with more flexibility.**

So, let me go through you a bit what the formula does,

**Array 1**

```
($A$2:$A$9=$J2) {TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE}
```

**Array 2**

```
($B$2:$B$9=$K2) {TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE}
```

**Array 3**

```
(TEXT($F$2:$F$9,"mmmmyyyy")=$I$1&YEAR(TODAY()))  

{FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE}
```

And this is the whole part which is wrapped within `SUMPRODUCT`

```
($G$2:$G$9)*($A$2:$A$9=$J2)*($B$2:$B$9=$K2)*(TEXT($F$2:$F$9,"mmmmyyyy")=$I$1&YEAR(TODAY()))
```

When you select this part and press F9, it evaluates and shows you an array of numbers

```
{0;0;0;0;0;0;12;0}
```

Basically its creates an array of TRUE's & FALSE's and then multiplies with the corresponding values to give you the exact output which you need!

**Also why you need to use SUMPRODUCT Function ---> Let me tell about it more**

It never gives an error for text values unless you are not using a double negative or double minus, I always say `SUMPRODUCT` is much versatile function than other, it can be clubbed with many other excel functions without any issue.

The **double negative (--)** is one of several ways to coerce **TRUE and FALSE** values into their numeric equivalents, 1 and 0. One we have 1s and 0s, we can perform various operations on the arrays with **Boolean logic**. The table below shows the result in **array1,array2, array3** based on the formula above, after the double negative (--) has changed the TRUE and FALSE values to 1s and 0s.

[image: ARRAY_TABLE]

Comment: I've actually never used sum product before, thanks for giving me a different option!

Comment: Ok, but i am explaining the whole aspect of `SUMPRODUCT` Function, how it works, no one does anything before but with time they need to learn more,

Comment: I agree 100%, I meant I didn't even think to try that. It seems to work just as well. Different avenue than I previously thought, this will definitely help me learn. Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah that's what i said, it is just amazing, incredible and versatile,!

Comment: @MILPDS refer this query, OP was using a formula which would slow down the functionality of excel engine, OP was using `FREQUENCY` Function within SUMPRODUCT, where as `SUMPRODUCT` alone can handle that query quite easily here is a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71048183/excel-combining-if-formula-with-frequencies-and-match

Comment: I've been using Excel every day since approximately the dawn of time and yet I did not know about that F9 trick

Comment: @JackDeeth Sir, if you are using since the dawn of time, then it may be your are joking with me

Comment: @MILPDS refer the table of multiplication, its so simple, you are are simply doing a multiplication of `TRUE` and `FALSE` !

Comment: So you commented on the other answer that TODAY() is volatile, which means your answer has the same disadvantage.

Comment: `" using TODAY() function is not recommended instead use cell references for the month, this is TODAY() is volatile and it shall always recalculate the sheet ! "` i have mentioned this, which goes for my solution as well and did you see the edited post of other answer, when i asked OP to use `SUMPRODUCT` -- In excel i believe anything & everything is possible here is one such example https://excelunusual.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can!

You'll need formulas to get the first date of this month and the next month:

```
Date(Year(Today()), Month(Today())    , 1))  -- first day of this month
Date(Year(Today()), Month(Today()) + 1, 1))  -- first day of next month
```

(This wraps the months intelligently i.e. `Date(2021, 13, 1)` is `2022-01-01`)

You can then use these with greater-than and less-than operators within SUMIFS:

```
= SUMIFS(
    value_column,
    date_column, ">=" & Date(Year(Today()), Month(Today())    , 1),
    date_column, "<"  & Date(Year(Today()), Month(Today()) + 1, 1)
)
```

For example:

```
= SUMIFS(
    G:G,
    F:F, ">=" & Date(Year(Today()), Month(Today())    , 1),
    F:F, "<"  & Date(Year(Today()), Month(Today()) + 1, 1),
    A:A, "primary",
    B:B, "panic"
)
```

So here it's picking up the `33` and `57` to calculate the sum of `90`.

[image: demo of the above]

---

###### Why this instead of `SumProduct`?

You can refer to entire columns e.g. `G:G` rather than a fixed range e.g. `G$2:G$9999`. `SumProduct` gives a `#VALUE!` error if any of the rows contain text, i.e. the column labels in the first row. `SumIfs` happily ignores the text.

---

###### Edit:

There may be a fault in this formula:

```
=SUMIFS($G$2:$G$100,$A$2:$A$100,"primary*",$B$2:$B$101,"little")+SUMIFS($G$2:$G$100,$F$2:$F$100,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1))
```

Making the format a little friendlier:

```
= SUMIFS(
    $G$2:$G$100,
    $A$2:$A$100, "primary*",
    $B$2:$B$101, "little"
)
+ SUMIFS(
    $G$2:$G$100,
    $F$2:$F$100, ">=" & DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)
)
```

It's adding all the Primary Littles from any month, and then also adding all the entries from this month onwards - double-counting any Primary Littles it's already counted.

Comment: Thanks for not only explaining how to set this up correctly, but explaining what was wrong with the previous formula! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Useful keyboard shortcut of the day: `Alt Enter` to put line breaks into cells, including when entering formulas. You can expand the formula bar and drag it down. In practice I hardly ever do this but it's helpful now and then.

Comment: I've actually had to use that recently, this sheet has gotten fairly robust (for me) in terms of a million different formulas that I thought i'd never use and quite a few macros for copying large amounts of data.

Comment: Yes, the formula used by OP is not right. More over to get month wise equation you need to use EOMONTH as well, otherwise it shall always give you the sum of 1st day of the month, to get month wise, you have to use it in this way, `=SUMIFS($G$2:$G$9,$F$2:$F$9,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),$F$2:$F$9,"<="&EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1),0))`

Comment: @MILPDS however using `TODAY()` function is not recommended instead use cell references for the month, this is `TODAY()` is volatile and it shall always recalculate the sheet !